# indexed column still takes 8 seconds, NOT using index (mysql 5)

Tags: mysql, indexing

Below is the result of a query that takes almost 8 seconds and there are indexes available but not being used. There are only 40,000 records.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (`phppos_customers`) 
   JOIN `phppos_people` ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id`
   WHERE `deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `last_name` asc LIMIT 20
    -> ;
** PERSONAL DATA REMOVED **

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM (`phppos_customers`) JOIN `phppos_people` ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id` WHERE `deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `last_name` asc LIMIT 20
    -> ;
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys     | key     | key_len | ref                            | rows  | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_customers | ref    | person_id,deleted | deleted | 4       | const                          | 22545 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | phppos_people    | eq_ref | PRIMARY           | PRIMARY | 4       | pos.phppos_customers.person_id |     1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+-------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe phppos_customers;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| person_id      | int(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| account_number | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| company_name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| taxable        | int(1)       | NO   |     | 1       |       |
| deleted        | int(1)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe phppos_people;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| first_name   | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| last_name    | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| phone_number | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| address_1    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address_2    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comments     | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| person_id    | int(10)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT: show create table phppos_customers;

```
| phppos_customers | CREATE TABLE `phppos_customers` (
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `taxable` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `account_number` (`account_number`),
  KEY `person_id` (`person_id`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_customers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_people` (`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

EDIT: show create table phppos_people;

```
| phppos_people | CREATE TABLE `phppos_people` (
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comments` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`),
  KEY `first_name` (`first_name`),
  KEY `last_name` (`last_name`),
  KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=45870 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

EDIT SHOW INDEXES:

```
mysql> show index from phppos_customers;
+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table            | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| phppos_customers |          0 | account_number |            1 | account_number | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| phppos_customers |          1 | person_id      |            1 | person_id      | A         |       46217 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| phppos_customers |          1 | deleted        |            1 | deleted        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+------------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from phppos_people;
+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| phppos_people |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | person_id   | A         |       45699 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| phppos_people |          1 | first_name |            1 | first_name  | A         |       45699 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| phppos_people |          1 | last_name  |            1 | last_name   | A         |       45699 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| phppos_people |          1 | email      |            1 | email       | A         |       45699 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+---------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Are those people's actual e-mails you've just posted? If so maybe you should edit and obscure them? P.S. you've got the index the wrong way round. It should be `deleted, person_id`.

Comment: I've edited out your table results, so you aren't exposing all your customers' names & emails publicly to search engines.

Comment: Sorry about that, thanks for the quick catch

Comment: what is the wrong query? Teh one you show says `2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Comment: The select query at the top that takes 7.98 seconds

Comment: Tried adding index as suggested: ALTER TABLE  `phppos_customers` ADD INDEX  `person_id_and_deleted` (  `deleted` ,  `person_id` );

still slow

Comment: Can you post the results of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for these? It looks as though you don't have a primary key for your php_pos customers table.

Comment: I have added the show create table statements

Comment: How many records in customers and how many in people?  Which table contains the "deleted" column?

Comment: There are 45,000+ customers, the deleted column is in the customers table.

Comment: Something doesn't look right. `customers.account_number` is a unique key with cardinality 2? Are there only 2 customers in the table?

Comment: Account number is not a required field, it can be null

Comment: What does `SELECT deleted, COUNT(*) FROM phppos_customers GROUP BY deleted;` give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the explain output this is what mysql does right now:

1. Start with `phppos_customers` table and use index on `deleted` to find rows with `deleted = 0`
2. For every row (22k of them left) find info from `phppos_people` for the same `person_id` (join).
3. Put everything in a temporary table and sort by `last_name` without any index to help with sorting as it is an already joined resultset, and all rows have to be sorted to find first 20.

This does not look like an optimal way to run this query, for some reason optimizer chose wrong join order.

Try forcing different join order using STRAIGHT_JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM `phppos_people` STRAIGHT_JOIN `phppos_customers` 
  ON `phppos_customers`.`person_id`=`phppos_people`.`person_id` 
WHERE `deleted` = 0 
ORDER BY `last_name` ASC LIMIT 20;
```

This time mysql should:

1. Start with `phppos_people` sorted by `last_name` using index on that column.
2. For every row join `phppos_customers` and check if `deleted = 0`.
3. Use limit optimization and stop after finding 20 first.